# java-script comman operator with different object

Tags: javascript

I was going through a library of a javascript plugin which was using this syntax.
what does the following statement means syntactically in JavaScript

```
simpleCart = function (options) {
    },$engine,cartColumnViews;
```

later the code uses simpleCart in many places. What does simpleCart refer to at the end of the statement.

EDIT1 : 
http://simplecartjs.org/assets/js/simpleCart-latest.php
search for "main simpleCart object"

Comment: Can you link to the source code?

Comment: Preceded by `var`: http://jsfiddle.net/p9tEg/. Without `var`: http://jsfiddle.net/p9tEg/1/

Comment: Are you missing the `var`?

Comment: Without the `var` on that fiddle `p9tEg/1` I get an error message in the console: `ReferenceError: $engine is not defined`

Comment: @gdoron i have added the link to the source code

Comment: @epascarello i am not missing var. I have pasted the link of the source code.

Answer (score 5):

My psychic powers tell me there's a `var` just before that (or just before a list of other values before that).

```
var a,b=2,c;
```

will define a, b and c, and set b to 2. So the code you found is setting simpleCart to a function, and defining $engine and cartColumnViews for future use (see the comments for really deep JavaScript details which are beyond the scope of this question!).

Comment: Assuming there is a `var` at the start, the OP code creates all the variables first, then assigns a function to `simpleCart` since declarations are processed before any code is executed. ;-)

Comment: well what do you know, seems it is. I had to make a jsfiddle to convince myself: http://jsfiddle.net/sfZPX/1/

Comment: well the answer is still valid anyway!

Answer (score 0):

That's very strange code, but the function and the `$engine` don't do anything so the result is essentially the same as `simpleCart = cartColumnViews`.

Comment: It's only "not correct" if there's a `var` we haven't been told about. The OP specifically said they were comma operators, so I went with it.

Comment: Practically it's the same as `throw 'referenceError: $engine is not defined'`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it is variable declaration.
simpleCart is variable that function assigned to it.

Better reference here:
[var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)